# Dynamics GP Webservices CountryRegionCodeKey

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I am creating a new sales order through the webservice.
I am setting the ShipToAddress property to a BusinessAddress class with a country code that is in a different country than the bill to address.
When I create the order and send it to GP there are no errors, GP gets the order; however, when I review the order and look at the ship to address the country code is not what I set it to, instead it seems to be using the bill to or main addresses country code.

```
    SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
    salesOrder.ShipToAddress = ConfigureDropShipAdress(shipToCustomer);

    private BusinessAddress ConfigureDropShipAdress(Customer dropShipCustomer)
    {
        var dropShipAddr = dropShipCustomer.Addresses.Where(a => a.Key.Id == "SHIP").FirstOrDefault();

        BusinessAddress busAddr = new BusinessAddress
        {
            ContactPerson = dropShipAddr.ContactPerson,
            Name = dropShipAddr.Name,
            Line1 = dropShipAddr.Line1,
            Line2 = dropShipAddr.Line2,
            Line3 = dropShipAddr.Line3,
            City = dropShipAddr.City,
            State = dropShipAddr.State,
            PostalCode = dropShipAddr.PostalCode,
            CountryRegion = dropShipAddr.CountryRegion, //This puts Unites States for our dropship customer
            CountryRegionCodeKey = dropShipAddr.CountryRegionCodeKey, // the code is correct at this point, but the country code is wrong in GP client... It is the original address's Ccode
            Phone1 = dropShipAddr.Phone1,
            Phone2 = dropShipAddr.Phone2,
            Phone3 = dropShipAddr.Phone3,
            Fax = dropShipAddr.Fax,
            ExtensionData = code.ExtensionData,
            Extensions = code.Extensions
        };

        return busAddr;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the sales order to use the country code I am setting?

Comment: Is this `salesOrder.ShipToAddress ` being over written before the final call to great plains?

Comment: No, Everything is correct but the country code. In the debugger it is all correct as well, then it gets sent over and the country code is no longer correct.

Comment: I haven't worked with GP, but I have experience with others ERPs.
Have you checked the GP settings? Your code looks ok.

Comment: @FernandaInesDuran Yea I checked the settings, but good idea.

Comment: Our DBA fixed this by writing an econnect sproc to determine what the Ccode should be by looking at the country and then updating the Ccode, we fixed two issues with this because setting of the country region key wasn't working correctly and our scribe integration wasn't working either.